# Как в C сделан полиморфизм?(Void* func)

Tags: c

В C тоже создается таблица виртуальных функций или это делается как-то по-другому?

P.S. не ругайтесь сильно, я новичок.

Comment: Полиморфизм это шаблонные классы. А вы про виртуальные функции... Что хотите коткретно?

Comment: А что вы понимаете под полиморфизмом в C?

Comment: @Harry Ну в Си можно делать указатели на функции, что дает возможно "перегружать" функции, если я правильно выразился.

Comment: Я бы не назвал это полиморфизмом. Это просто указатель на функцию. И вызов по указателю - такой же, как и обычный `CALL`.

Comment: @Harry Тогда, что такое полиморфизм в вашем понимании?

Comment: Суть вопроса не ясна. В языке С даже отдаленно нет никакого "полиморфизма", для которого могла бы понадобиться таблица виртуальных функций. Для реализации обычных указателей на функции не нужна никакая "таблица виртуальных функций"

Comment: полиморфизм - предоставление единого интерфейса для объектов разных типов. Виртуальные функции обеспечивают динамический (run-time) полиморфизм через интерфейс, предоставляемый базовым классом. Перегруженные функции и шаблоны обеспечивают статический (компиляционный) полиморфизм. TС++ PL 12.2.6, 13.6.1, D & E 2.9.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/37576/

Comment: @Ant Хорошо, я немного прочитал про статический(как я понял в си, что-то вроде этого) и динамический полиморфизм, и у меня возник вопрос: а зачем нужен динамический, если у нас есть статический? Это ведь быстрее.

Comment: @kaylil_01, не всегда возможно использовать статический полиморфизм.